# Use Javascript to add a CSS class according of child number (HTML)

Tags: javascript, css, grid

Need some help for that.
I want to create a dynamic portfolio class with css and js.
I can't seem to get my wrapper element to take an extra class depending on the number of HTLM children in the div.
if there are 5 children the element will have to take the class "wrapper5" if there are 4 children it will take the class "wrapper4" etc ...
These css classes just need to add a grid-template-areas.

Hope you have info to help me find a solution.
(and sorry for my english)

```js
let port = document.getElementById("wrapper");

if (port.childNodes.length = 4) {
  port.classList.add("wrapper4")
} else if (port.childNodes.length = 3) {
  port.classList.add("wrapper3")
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 5vh;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 99vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#wrapper5 {
  grid-template-areas: "image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image5 image5" "image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image5 image5" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

#wrapper4 {
  grid-template-areas: "image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4" "image3 image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image2" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

#wrapper3 {
  grid-template-areas: "image3 image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image2" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

.flex1 {
  grid-area: image1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #4281a4;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex2 {
  grid-area: image2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #E6B89C;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex3 {
  grid-area: image3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FE938C;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex4 {
  grid-area: image4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #EAD2AC;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex5 {
  grid-area: image5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #9CAFB7;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
    <div class="flex5">Image 5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: `=` is still the _assignment_ operator in JavaScript, comparison is `==`.

Comment: `port.classList.add("wrapper" + port.childNodes.length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your ids to classes you can have a truly dynamic solution - which will work not just on loading but if images are added or taken away e.g. by user action while running.

We look for all the elements with class wrapper and take away any wrapper class they might already have and add a class called wrapper + number of children they have. No need for conditional statements.

[image]

```html
<head>
<style>
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 5vh;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 99vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.wrapper5 {
  grid-template-areas: "image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image5 image5" "image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image5 image5" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

.wrapper4 {
  grid-template-areas: "image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4" "image3 image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image2" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

.wrapper3 {
  grid-template-areas: "image3 image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image2" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

.flex1 {
  grid-area: image1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #4281a4;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex2 {
  grid-area: image2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #E6B89C;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex3 {
  grid-area: image3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FE938C;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex4 {
  grid-area: image4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #EAD2AC;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex5 {
  grid-area: image5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #9CAFB7;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
    <div class="flex5">Image 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
<script>

function updateWrappers() {
  let ports = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
  for (let i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
    let port = ports[i];
    port.classList = 'wrapper';
    port.classList.add('wrapper' + port.children.length);
  }
}

updateWrappers();
// for a truly dynamic situation add a mutationObserver which runs updateWrappers if anything added/subtracted
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's a great method. Indeed my goal is to obtain a totally dynamic portfolio thanks to javascript. I adapted my code to yours and it didn't work.
So I created a new project and literally copied and pasted your code to make sure I didn't make a copy error and it still doesn't work. I am ???

Comment: I just tried on one and the same HTML page and now I get the same result. This must be relative to the javascript function. I have to call it another way maybe.

Comment: Yes sorry I can speak English. Your code works.
I created a new html page in which I pasted all your and it shows me the templates associated with the number of children. It's when I use different HTML, CSS, and JS files that it doesn't work anymore. I think it has to do with javascript not being correctly called this way but it is strange.

Comment: Are you calling the update function after the function code (i.e. when it has definitely loaded)? You should be able to call that function anywhere in your code once it's loaded. Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: I added "<script> updateWrappers (); </script>" in my html file and there the javascript applies.
  I thought that since the function call was done in the .js file I won't need to redo it in my HTML.
In any case, thank you! I just have to try to implement a mutationObserver () for a totally dynamic result as you say.

Comment: You might want to thank the w3c that this works and doesn't throw a `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have multiple `id`'s. Just use id `wrapper1`, `wrapper2` and so on.

```html
<div class="content">
    <div id="wrapper1">
        <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
        <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
        <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
        <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
        <div class="flex5">Image 5</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2">
        <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
        <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
        <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
        <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper3">
        <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
        <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
        <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for the js, `=` is an assignment operator not equality check. You can use double equals `==` for equality checking.

```
let port = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper1, #wrapper2, #wrapper3");

port.forEach((el) => {
    if (el.childNodes.length == 4) {
        el.classList.add("image-4");
    }
      else if (el.childNodes.length == 3) {
          el.classList.add("image-3");
      }
});
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to update my HTML code. I had already changed the name of the IDs to "wrapper" for the 3 div. How come we use "el" and not port?
Yes, I understand for the "==" I had not thought of this detail at all, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You can't access several `id`'s, they are supposed to be unique. Better use a `class`.
2. `childNodes` will count all the items inside the element, including text, resulting in a bigger number than expected. Use `children` instead. Accordin to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes): "childNodes includes all child nodes—including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes".
3. you are using `=` (assignment) instead of `===` (comparision). You can use `==` or `===`, but using the strict equality operator `===` is considered a best practice

```js
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");

for(let i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++){
  if (wrappers[i].children.length === 4) {
      wrappers[i].classList.add("wrapper4")
  } else if (wrappers[i].children.length === 3) {
    wrappers[i].classList.add("wrapper3")
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
          <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
          <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
          <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
          <div class="flex5">Image 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
        <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
        <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
        <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
      <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
      <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I past your code in my main.js I don't know why this don't works. On my front there is only one image which is displayed each time by ".wrapper"

Answer (score 0):

If you change your ids to classes you can have a truly dynamic solution - which will work not just on loading but if images are added or taken away e.g. by user action while running.

We look for all the elements with class wrapper and take away any wrapper class they might already have and add a class called wrapper + number of children they have. No need for conditional statements.

```html
<head>
<style>
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 5vh;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 99vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.wrapper5 {
  grid-template-areas: "image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image5 image5" "image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image5 image5" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

.wrapper4 {
  grid-template-areas: "image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image4" "image3 image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image2" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

.wrapper3 {
  grid-template-areas: "image3 image3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image2 image2" "image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1 image1";
}

.flex1 {
  grid-area: image1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #4281a4;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex2 {
  grid-area: image2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #E6B89C;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex3 {
  grid-area: image3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FE938C;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex4 {
  grid-area: image4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #EAD2AC;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex5 {
  grid-area: image5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #9CAFB7;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
    <div class="flex5">Image 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
    <div class="flex4">Image 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="flex2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="flex3">Image 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
<script>

function updateWrappers() {
  let ports = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
  for (let i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
    let port = ports[i];
    port.classList = 'wrapper';
    port.classList.add('wrapper' + port.children.length);
  }
}

updateWrappers();
// for a truly dynamic situation add a mutationObserver which runs updateWrappers if anything added/subtracted
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

ids can not apply more then one elements, that is the main difference between classes and ids.